# Assign checkbox items to MySQL db TEXT column

Tags: php, mysql, forms

My HTML form has three check boxes;

```
<input type="checkbox" name="numb" value="1">1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="numb" value="2">2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="numb" value="3">3
```

How can I assign the checked items into a TEXT variable of a MySQL database, separated by a single space?

Comment: What does your PHP / SQL code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have the values of the checkboxes if all of them have same name, assign different name to all checkboxes to get their values:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="numb1" value="1">1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="numb2" value="2">2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="numb3" value="3">3
```

then, through PHP, check if they have been `check`ed, if so, fetch their values :

```
$text =""; /*create variable to save data */
if(isset($_POST['numb1'])) /* check if the check box is checked */
    {
     $text = $text." ".trim($_POST['numb1']);
    }

if(isset($_POST['numb2'])) /* check if the check box is checked */
    {
      $text = $text." ".trim($_POST['numb2']);
    }

if(isset($_POST['numb3'])) /* check if the check box is checked */
    {
      $text = $text." ".trim($_POST['numb3']);
    }
```

Now you have the data in `$text` variable to push in the database.

Before the final insert in the db, you can `trim` the `$text` again to remove any other `white-space` but it totally depends on the checkbox values (*if they contain spaces or not in the html markup*)

Comment: And how does OP put it in the Database?

Comment: @putvande : added the edit...please validate! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the name into an array

```
<input type="checkbox" name="numb[]" value="1">1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="numb[]" value="2">2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="numb[]" value="3">3
```

and in php

```
$numb = '';
if ( isset($_POST['numb']) ) {
   foreach( $_POST['numb'] as $n ) {
      $numb .= $n . ' ';
   }
   $numb = trim($numb);
}
```

and insert the `$numb` into the mysql table

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way can be
`$val = implode(" ",$_POST["numb"]);`

now `$val` hold all values with a space. you can simply store it in db.

Comment: ...and from where is the `id` coming, i don't see it anywhere in markup???

Comment: sorry, just edited. it's actually name of input (check boxes).